# Excel VBA: get google view-source

Tags: excel, vba

With Excel VBA, I would like to get the text shown on the browser if you write

> "view-source:https://www.google.com/search?q=Something"

.

How can I do that?

something like

```
Dim Str as String
Str = getText("view-source:https://www.google.com/search?q=Something")
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need view-source. I believe that will do:

```
Sub http()
    Dim MyRequest As Object

    Set MyRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    MyRequest.Open "GET", "https://www.google.com/search?q=Something"

    MyRequest.Send

    'Output to immediate window
    Debug.Print MyRequest.ResponseText

End Sub
```